# /bin/sh alternative to ${!#} in /bin/bash

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm trying to understand what is the alternative of `${!#}` of `/bin/bash` on `/bin/sh`?

I know that `${!#}`, which evaluated to `${0}` on `/bin/bash` but how can I get it using `/bin/sh`?

Answer (score 2):

The closest approximation you can get in sh is an `eval`-based solution.

```
eval echo "\$${#}"
```

But keep in mind that eval is very dangerous if not used carefully. I'd recommend considering if you need indirection or not before implementing.

For example, the above code basically reduces to "print the last argument." You could write this without using indirection or eval:

```
for arg in "${0}" "${@}" ; do
:
done
echo "${arg}"
```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with using `eval` in this case.

You should wrap `$#` in curly braces though; otherwise it won't work when the number of positional parameters exceeds nine. See:

```bash
$ set -- a b c d e f g h i j
$ eval "arg=\$$#"
$ echo "$arg"
a0
$
$ eval "arg=\${$#}"
$ echo "$arg"
j
```